# How to remove % sign when submit a long text and when retreiving it through post method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form and in that form there is a text area called offer and I need to pass the text entered in to that text area into other page by post method when submit button is clicked. But when it retrieves, that entered text is displayed just like this:

```
I%20would%20like%20to%20buy%20your%20vehicle
```

How can I remove that?

**reviewOfferView.php**

```
 <form name="myform5" action="<?php echo base_url().'submitOfferCtrl/submitOffer/'. $email.'/'. $offer.'/'. $msg .'/'. $id;?>" method="POST">
```

**submitOfferCtrl.php**

```
public function submitOffer($selleremail,$offer,$msg,$id)
    {
        $this->main_model->submitOffer($selleremail,$offer,$msg,$id);
        $config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'dtt@gmail.com', 
                'smtp_pass' => 'dtt1',
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
            );
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('dtt@gmail.com');
        $this->email->to($selleremail); 
        $this->data['posts']=$this->main_model->getOffer($selleremail,$id);
        $this->email->subject('A offer has been made on your advertisement');
        $body=$this->load->view('pages/sendOffer',$this->data,TRUE);
        $this->email->message($body);   

        if($this->email->send())
        {   
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Your message has been sent succesfully through email');
            redirect("http://localhost/ci/ads_ctrl");   
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Check your internet connection and try again');
            redirect("http://localhost/ci/ads_ctrl");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to wrap the string with http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php ?

Comment: Is your form method `method="get"` or no method at all, or is it `post`?

Comment: @Rasclatt it's "post" method

Comment: It says post in his question.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh, so it does. Can you post your form?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @AmitRajput I posted my code

Comment: @mad_ss is this full code of "reviewOfferView.php"?

Comment: @AmitRajput No I just posted the one line from the code  that i thought will be useful for you to answer my qusetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `urldecode()`?

This isn't being submitted via `$_POST`. It's being submitted through `$_GET`. If you can pull it from the URL, it isn't a `$_POST` submission, regardless of what you say in your form declaration.

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
```

Would open your form. There's also a close tag. You can include parameters in the parentheses to call the correct method.

You'd then sanitize/prepare your form input for email submission. You wouldn't get it from the URL.

**Edit**

If you insist on going this route,

```
$msg = urldecode($msg);
```

Should remove the %20 spaces.

**Edit #2**

I can't recommend this.

Comment: thanks :-) $msg = urldecode($msg)  this code solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace()` function like this:

```
str_replace('%', ' ', $stringToReplace);
```

I Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use urlencode() and urldecode() methods for this. like below

reviewOfferView.php

```
<form name="myform5" action="<?php echo base_url().'submitOfferCtrl/submitOffer/'. $email.'/'. urlencode($offer).'/'. urlencode($msg) .'/'. $id;?>" method="POST">
```

submitOfferCtrl.php

```
public function submitOffer($selleremail,$offer,$msg,$id)
{
    $offer = urldecode($offer);
    $msg = urldecode($msg);

   // your code here..  

}
```